# Magento newsletter popup (modal window) firing off on every page. It should only popup on the homepage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, popup

I've been having this ongoing problem where my newsletter modal window popup is firing off on every single page on the website. It's very intrusive and I would like it only to popup when a user visits the homepage. I'm running on EE Magento ver. 1.13.1.0

The code I've tried is below and it's placed in footer.phtml:

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getPageId() == '2' && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms') : ?>    

<div id="newsletter_sign_up" style="display:none;" >

<div style="padding:20px;" >
<form action="<?php echo($this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new')) ?>" method="post" >
  <div class="fieldset">

    <h1 style="color: #28ced7; text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 28px;">verbiage goes here</h1>

    <h2 class="legend" style="text-align:left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">verbiage goes here</h2>
    <!--end-->
    <ul class="form-list">
      <li class="fields">
        <div class="customer-name">
          <div class="field name-firstname">
            <label class="required" for="firstname" style="text-align:left;"><em>*</em>First Name</label>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="255" title="First Name" value="" name="firstname" id="firstname" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field name-lastname">
            <label class="required" for="lastname" style="text-align:left;"><em>*</em>Last Name</label>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="255" title="Last Name" value="" name="lastname" id="lastname" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="required" for="email_address"  style="text-align:left;"><em>*</em>Email Address</label>
        <div class="input-box">

          <input type="text" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" title="Email Address" value="" id="email_address" name="email" autocomplete="off"/>

      <input class="pop_newsletter_source" name="source" type="hidden" value="3" />

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-set form-buttons">
    <button onclick="pop_newsletter.submit(); return false;" title="Submit" class="button" type="submit" autocomplete="off" style="position: relative; right: 140px;"><span><span>Submit</span></span></button>
  </div>
  <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>

  <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;">Email Privacy Statement:</h2>
  <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; text-align: left;">more verbiage</p>
  <!--//end-->
</form>
</div>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I've checked to verify that the page id is 2.

```
<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getPageId()); echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

Additionally, I've found this code snippet here on stack but to no avail, it doesn't work correctly either.

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms') : ?>
```

If it helps that i post the JS then i'll do so too. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code placed in header or footer and is getting cached on every page?

Comment: I'm sorry, i should of specified that; it's currently placed in the footer.

Comment: I think its possibly due to caching of footer. Basically we cache your footer in most of the FPC modules because footer content are almost similler on every page. In your case, this html is dynamic. Hence, if you have FPC, you need to specify your model child block in "Dynamic Blocks" for cache so that it is rendered on every page dynamically which will also check your if conditions every time.

Comment: I'm not certain what FPC means.

Comment: FPC stands for Full Page Cache. In this, you specify the blocks you want to get cached on every page so that instead of requesting for them from server, browser renders them from the cache. You can check more about it here :  http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/understanding-full-page-cache/          I am not quite sure if this is the reason, this might be one of the reasons your model appearing on every page.

Comment: Okay, it's a little bit clearer now and makes more sense. Any idea how to work around this to sort this problem out?

Comment: What we are looking for is called Hole Punching. This link might help you to understand and get this sorted : http://www.techytalk.info/hole-punching-with-magento-enterprise-edition-full-page-cache/ :)